# Exercise fermat numbers

Tags: arithmetic, fermat-numbers

Someone can help me with this problem?
$F_p=2^{2^p}+1$

1. Prove that for $2^n+1$ be prime, n have to be a power of 2.
2. Prove that for $k\ge1$ $F_p \mid F_{p+k}-2$
3. Deduce that $F_p$ and $F_{p+k}$ are primes between them.
4. Deduce that there are an infinity of prime numbers.

I don't know how to do the 1 nor the 4.

Comment: For 1), suppose $n=mq$, where $m$ is odd and $\gt 1$. Then $2^n+1=(2^q)^m+1$. Let $x=2^q$. Then $x+1$ divides $x^m+1$.

Comment: Thank you! Any idea for the 4?

Comment: It is an immediate consequence of (2) and (3). Let $p_k$ be the smallest prime divisor of $F_k$ (any prime factor will also work). The $p_k$ are distinct, because any two different Fermat numbers are relatively prime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

For 2), use induction on $k$, remembering that $2^{2^{p+k}}=\bigl(2^{2^p}\bigr)^{2^k}$.

For 4): use that each Fermat number has a prime factor.

Comment: Okey, the serie is infinite and every number of the serie if formed by at least one prime divisor who is different from all the primes that form the predecessors of this number, so infinite primes.